# Are Foreground Services counted as app usage under Android 11's permission auto reset feature?

Tags: android

With Android 11, permissions are auto-reset if the app is not used in a period of time (3 months of inactivity?), While the Android documentation states that the app's "usage" is determined by:

- Interaction with the app (i.e. opening the app)
- Interaction with a widget
- Interaction with a notification (no including swiping the notification away)

My question is are foreground services on counted towards interacting with the app or does the user have to open the app itself for it to be marked as recently used?

For example, if the app's purpose is to connect to a bluetooth peripheral, and is capable of connecting in the background and starting a foreground service when connected to maintain the communication with the device, would this count as the app being used if the foreground service is active or could the user connect to the device everyday for 3 months (starting the foreground service each time) and the app would still have all permissions revoked due to the app actually not being opened?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What happens when you try to expire the permissions manually while the FG service is running? Also, would https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/app-hibernation#request-user-disable-hibernation help to workaround?